# Enable IDENTITY_INSERT in doctrine 2

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine-orm, sqlsrv

I own an mssql database server, and connect to it using doctrine2(sqlsrv)

I would like to create the new entity instances with a given id. But if I try it, I get an error:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'my_test_table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

I've removed the `@GeneratedValue` annotation. But I still get this error.

After that, I've run this script in the `SQL Server management studio:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT my_test_table ON
```

Unfortunately I still get the error, and I can't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be called on the doctrine's connection

```
$em->getConnection()->prepare("SET IDENTITY_INSERT my_test_table ON")->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something may be different with my setup, or something in Doctrine may have  changed, but this wouldn't work for me with Doctrine ORM 2.5.6, PHP 7.0.17, and SQL Server 2014.

Despite setting it before my flush, it wouldn't work. It also couldn't work for multiple tables from a class hierarchy as IDENTITY_INSERT can be on for only one table at a time.

I was able to figure out how to do this by using a wrapper class for the connection. Doctrine supports this with the [`wrapperClass`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#wrapper-class) configuration parameter. Below is my code that worked.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Application\Db;

/**
 * Class SqlSrvIdentityInsertConnection
 * This class is to enable Identity Insert when using Doctrine with SQLServer. 
 * Must use this class with the "wrapperClass" configuration option 
 * for EntityManager::create
 */
class SqlSrvIdentityInsertConnection extends \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
{
    private $tables = [];
    private $enabled = [];

    public function enableIdentityInsertFor(string $tableName)
    {
        $this->tables[] = $tableName;
        $this->enabled[$tableName] = false;
    }

    private function setIdentityInsert(string $statement) {
        // Must turn off IDENTITY_INSERT if it was enabled, and this table
        // isn't in the query. Must do this first!
        foreach($this->tables as $tableName) {
            if (stristr($statement, "INSERT INTO $tableName") === false) {
                if ($this->enabled[$tableName]) {
                    parent::exec("SET IDENTITY_INSERT " . $tableName . " OFF");
                    $this->enabled[$tableName] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach($this->tables as $tableName) {
            if (stristr($statement, "INSERT INTO $tableName") !== false) {
                parent::exec("SET IDENTITY_INSERT ".$tableName." ON");
                $this->enabled[$tableName] = true;

                // Only one can be enabled at a time
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public function prepare($statement)
    {
        $this->setIdentityInsert($statement);
        return parent::prepare($statement);
    }
}
```

Here is how it is used when you want to insert some entities with

```
    $em->persist($newEntity);

    /** @var SqlSrvIdentityInsertConnection $conn */
    $conn = $em->getConnection();

    $metadata = $this->session->getClassMetaData(MyEntityClass::class);
    $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
    $conn->enableIdentityInsertFor($metadata->getTableName());

    $em->flush();
```